# Convert JSON to POJO retrofit2

Tags: java, retrofit, pojo

How can I describe the POJO for such an answer so that the retrofit understands it? the response comes in this form. I cut it, in order to see the structure of JSON. nested objects I converted to POJO. I want to learn how to convert the main object?

```
[
    [
    "all_areas",
    {
      "6": {
        "id": "6",
        "parent_id": "0",
        "left_key": "1",
        "right_key": "6594",
        "level": "1",
        "title": "Вся Россия",
        "alias": "vsya_rossiya",
        "sort": "1",        
        "navigatorListItems": []
      },
      "7": {
        "id": "7",
        "parent_id": "6",
        "left_key": "2",
        "right_key": "31",
        "level": "2",
        "title": "Адыгея респ.",
        "alias": "adygeya_resp",
        "sort": "1",       
        "navigatorListItems": []
      }
    }
  ],
  [
    "current_rubrics",
    [
      {
        "id": "7",
        "parent_id": "6",
        "left_key": "2",
        "right_key": "19",
        "level": "2",
        "title": "Недвижимость",
        "alias": "nedvizhimost",
        "sort": "1"
      },
      {
        "id": "8",
        "parent_id": "6",
        "left_key": "20",
        "right_key": "47",
        "level": "2",
        "title": "Транспорт",
        "alias": "transport",
        "sort": "2"
      }
    ]
  ]
  ]
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: many different ways. The main array contains many arrays, the zero element of the string contains the name of the array, and the first element is the desired object. The whole problem is that there is not a single key in the main array

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818895/how-to-map-a-dynamic-json-property-to-a-fixed-pojo-field

Comment: This is a different situation. In that question, the data comes in the form of a "key": "value". but in my main object, there is no such structure

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is what a Json should look like

```
{
"all_areas": [{
"6": {
  "id": "6",
  "parent_id": "0",
  "left_key": "1",
  "right_key": "6594",
  "level": "1",
  "title": "Вся Россия",
  "alias": "vsya_rossiya",
  "sort": "1",
  "navigatorListItems": []
}
},

{
"7": {
  "id": "7",
  "parent_id": "6",
  "left_key": "2",
  "right_key": "31",
  "level": "2",
  "title": "Адыгея респ.",
  "alias": "adygeya_resp",
  "sort": "1",
  "navigatorListItems": []
}
}
],
"current_rubrics": [{
  "id": "7",
  "parent_id": "6",
  "left_key": "2",
  "right_key": "19",
  "level": "2",
  "title": "Недвижимость",
  "alias": "nedvizhimost",
  "sort": "1"
},
{
  "id": "8",
  "parent_id": "6",
  "left_key": "20",
  "right_key": "47",
  "level": "2",
  "title": "Транспорт",
  "alias": "transport",
  "sort": "2"
 }
 ]
}
```

Copy this and convert it to pojo using the website [http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) or any another website which does the conversion for you

Answer (score -1):

**This will be your main model class:**

```
public class Testing
  {
   private 7 7;

   private 6 6;

public 7 get7 ()
{
    return 7;
}

public void set7 (7 7)
{
    this.7 = 7;
}

public 6 get6 ()
{
    return 6;
}

public void set6 (6 6)
{
    this.6 = 6;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [7 = "+7+", 6 = "+6+"]";
}
 }
```

**then there will be two subclasses (7.java & 6.java):**

> 7.java

```
 public class 7
 {
private String[] navigatorListItems;

private String id;

private String left_key;

private String title;

private String sort;

private String level;

private String alias;

private String right_key;

private String parent_id;

public String[] getNavigatorListItems ()
{
    return navigatorListItems;
}

public void setNavigatorListItems (String[] navigatorListItems)
{
    this.navigatorListItems = navigatorListItems;
}

public String getId ()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId (String id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public String getLeft_key ()
{
    return left_key;
}

public void setLeft_key (String left_key)
{
    this.left_key = left_key;
}

public String getTitle ()
{
    return title;
}

public void setTitle (String title)
{
    this.title = title;
}

public String getSort ()
{
    return sort;
}

public void setSort (String sort)
{
    this.sort = sort;
}

public String getLevel ()
{
    return level;
}

public void setLevel (String level)
{
    this.level = level;
}

public String getAlias ()
{
    return alias;
}

public void setAlias (String alias)
{
    this.alias = alias;
}

public String getRight_key ()
{
    return right_key;
}

public void setRight_key (String right_key)
{
    this.right_key = right_key;
}

public String getParent_id ()
{
    return parent_id;
}

public void setParent_id (String parent_id)
{
    this.parent_id = parent_id;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [navigatorListItems = "+navigatorListItems+", id = "+id+", left_key = "+left_key+", title = "+title+", sort = "+sort+", level = "+level+", alias = "+alias+", right_key = "+right_key+", parent_id = "+parent_id+"]";
}
  }
```

> 6.java

```
public class 6
{
private String[] navigatorListItems;

private String id;

private String left_key;

private String title;

private String sort;

private String level;

private String alias;

private String right_key;

private String parent_id;

public String[] getNavigatorListItems ()
{
    return navigatorListItems;
}

public void setNavigatorListItems (String[] navigatorListItems)
{
    this.navigatorListItems = navigatorListItems;
}

public String getId ()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId (String id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public String getLeft_key ()
{
    return left_key;
}

public void setLeft_key (String left_key)
{
    this.left_key = left_key;
}

public String getTitle ()
{
    return title;
}

public void setTitle (String title)
{
    this.title = title;
}

public String getSort ()
{
    return sort;
}

public void setSort (String sort)
{
    this.sort = sort;
}

public String getLevel ()
{
    return level;
}

public void setLevel (String level)
{
    this.level = level;
}

public String getAlias ()
{
    return alias;
}

public void setAlias (String alias)
{
    this.alias = alias;
}

public String getRight_key ()
{
    return right_key;
}

public void setRight_key (String right_key)
{
    this.right_key = right_key;
}

public String getParent_id ()
{
    return parent_id;
}

public void setParent_id (String parent_id)
{
    this.parent_id = parent_id;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [navigatorListItems = "+navigatorListItems+", id = "+id+", left_key = "+left_key+", title = "+title+", sort = "+sort+", level = "+level+", alias = "+alias+", right_key = "+right_key+", parent_id = "+parent_id+"]";
}
 }
```

Comment: Dude are you serious? Which programming language supports numbers as data type for the variables (or even for class names)?

Comment: Did you try creating these classes in any one of the Java IDEs (with numbers as data type and variable name)? If that website generates POJO classes (also variables) with numbers, doesn't mean it's valid. You can try the same JSON data with http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and see the difference. Here is an official documentation for Java variable [naming convention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)